# The output of following program given to me and its just not clicking.The answer is 6 3 which is clearly not understood by me

Tags: java, output, increment, decrement

```
class ab {
    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        int x = 0, y = 0;

        for (int z = 0; z < 5; z++)
        {

            if (++x > 2 && ++y > 2)
            {
                x++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(x + " " + y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you thought of running this through a debugger ?

Comment: We don't know what you don't understand about it. Trace the execution on paper; or use a debugger to step through.

Comment: Yes . I traced it on paper nearly 10 times now and iv been getting 8 5 all along.

Comment: @Marged I tried on a debugger and 6 3 is the answer which is clearly not matching my dry run output.

Comment: @vicky are you paying attention to the short circuit semantics of `&&`, i.e. that the right hand operand is only evaluated when the left hand operand is true?

Comment: I meant step by step, then you can see the difference between code and paper

Answer (score 2):

`&&` is a short-circuiting operator, which means `++y > 2` is not evaluated until `++x` is at least `3`. In this case, we can trivially add debugging messages to obtain values for `x`, `y` and `z` before and after the `if` block to see **exactly** what happens (and when). Like,

```
int x = 0, y = 0;
for (int z = 0; z < 5; z++) {
    System.out.printf("Before: x = %d, y = %d, z = %d%n", x, y, z);
    if (++x > 2 && ++y > 2) {
        System.out.printf("Inside: x = %d, y = %d, z = %d%n", x, y, z);
        x++;
    }
    System.out.printf("After:  x = %d, y = %d, z = %d%n", x, y, z);
}
System.out.println(x + " " + y);
```

Which hopefully clarifies any remaining confusion

```
Before: x = 0, y = 0, z = 0
After:  x = 1, y = 0, z = 0
Before: x = 1, y = 0, z = 1
After:  x = 2, y = 0, z = 1
Before: x = 2, y = 0, z = 2
After:  x = 3, y = 1, z = 2
Before: x = 3, y = 1, z = 3
After:  x = 4, y = 2, z = 3
Before: x = 4, y = 2, z = 4
Inside: x = 5, y = 3, z = 4
After:  x = 6, y = 3, z = 4
6 3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are finding that you think the output is `8 5`, you are overlooking a subtle fact:

```
if (++x > 2 && ++y > 2)
```

The `&&` operator is a *short-circuiting* operator. This means that the right-hand operand is only evaluated when the left-hand operand is true.

There is a non-short-circuiting and operator - `&` - which always evaluates both; but that isn't what is being used here. If you replace `&&` with `&`, you do indeed get `8 5`. `&&` and `&` give logically the same result if there are no side effects in evaluation of the operands, so `&&` is used far more often (to the extent that I don't remember the last time I read boolean `&` in actual code, never mind wrote one) because it avoids unnecessary work.

So, on the first 2 iterations of the loop, `x` is incremented without incrementing `y`.

After that, both `x` and `y` are incremented.

You could have found this yourself by using a debugger, or just printing out the values of `x` and `y` on each loop iteration. You'd have quickly found the difference vs your on-paper working.

Comment: Got it. Thanks mate, Will try to use debugger more often now.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok it is very simple let have a look.

First time when `z = 0` `for` loop reach at the `if` statement when it checks the left side first where `++i` is pre-increment so `i` becomes **1** before comparison then `1 > 2` returns **false**  which does not check the second part.

Now `z = 1` and again pre-increment and `i = 2` which again condition returns **false** and y still at 0

Now `z = 2` and `i = 3` which `3 > 2` which return **true** now and now there will be pre-increment at `y` and `y=1` but returns **false**

Now `z = 3` and `i = 4` and then `y =2` which again return `2 > 2` **false**

Now `z= 4` and `i = 5`and `y = 3` and both condition in `if` statements returns **true** and its body executes which mean a post increment in x and x will be `x= 6`

now `z = 5` and `for` loop condition return **false** and loop **break**

And at last `System.out.println(x + " " + y);` returns **6** and **3**

**Note:** if condition executed only one time